# Django counter in loop to index list

Tags: python, django

I'm passing two lists to a template.  Normally if I was iterating over a list I would do something like this

```
{% for i in list %}
```

but I have two lists that I need to access in parallel, ie. the nth item in one list corresponds to the nth item in the other list.  My thought was to loop over one list and access an item in the other list using forloop.counter0 but I can't figure out the syntax to get that to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can't. The simple way is to preprocess you data in a [zipped list](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip), like this

In your view

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [4, 5, 6]
zipped = zip(x, y)
```

Then in you template :

```
{% for x, y in zipped %}
    {{ x }} - {{ y }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: do you think that this is a better solution than using a multifor?  I certainly like that is results in a simpler template

Comment: @Xavier I've tried this to pass list with formset (for extra non input context) it renders perfectly but the formset doesn't submit! how to solve that ?

Answer (score 21):

To access an iterable using a forloop counter I've coded the following very simple filter:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def index(sequence, position):
    return sequence[position]
```

And then I can use it at my templates as (don't forget to load it):

```
{% for item in iterable1 %}
  {{ iterable2|index:forloop.counter0 }}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: This, although taking a few additional steps to implement, allows for the usage that `forloop.counter0` should provide with variables in for loops.  I changed the return statement to: `return sequence[position]` for my needs.

Comment: @Flash I'm actually using `sequence[position]` in my real code too, updated here!

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like you're looking for my [django-multiforloop](https://github.com/gabrielgrant/django-multiforloop). From the README:

Rendering this template

```
{% load multifor %}
{% for x in x_list; y in y_list %}
  {{ x }}:{{ y }}
{% endfor %}
```

with this context

```
context = {
    "x_list": ('one', 1, 'carrot'),
    "y_list": ('two', 2, 'orange')
}
```

will output

```
one:two
1:2
carrot:orange
```

Answer (score 7):

I ended up having to do this:

```
{% for x in x_list %}
  {% for y in y_list %}
    {% if forloop.counter == forloop.parentloop.counter %}
       Do Something
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I think it's an `O(n^2)` solution when you could do it in simply `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

don't think you'll be able to do it like that.  You'll need either a template tag, or much better, to align the lists in your view logic, before passing an aligned data structure to you template.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by adding placeholder properties such as template_property1 to one of the models.

Then add logic in the views.py function to loop through both models and assign values across:

```
model1 = Model1.objects.all()
model2 = Model2.objects.all()

for m1 in model1:                          (loop through model1) 
  for m2 in model2:                        (loop through model2)
    if m2.FK == m1:                        (MATCH SOME CRITERIA)   
      m1.template_property1 = m2.property  (ASSIGN VALUE)
```

then access all values through a single Model object int the template
for m1 in model1
{{ model1.template_property1 ))