# Django same name multiple input insert to DB

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have multiple same name inputs. html created with jquery and json.

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="product_id" value="xyz" />
<p class="left">
    <label class="name">General</label> 
    <input type="hidden" value="2" name="location_id">
    <input type="text" name="location_stock" placeholder="Quantity" class="text small right" value="5">
</p>
<p class="left">
    <label class="name">warehouse 1</label>
    <input type="hidden" value="5" name="location_id">
    <input class="text small right" type="text" name="location_stock" placeholder="Quantity" value="7">
</p>
<p class="left">
    <label class="name">warehouse 2</label>
    <input type="hidden" value="6" name="location_id">
    <input class="text small right" type="text" name="location_stock" placeholder="Quantity" value="8">
</p>
```

Json

```
$.getJSON(url, function(models) {
    var options = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < models.length; i++) {
        options += '<p class="left"><label class="name">' + models[i].fields['name'] + '</label></span> <input type="hidden" name="location_id" value="' + models[i].pk + '" /><input type="text" class="text small right" placeholder="Quantity" name="location_stock" /></p>' 
    }
    $(".widget.stock_details").append(options);
    $("#stock_locations option:first").attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

I want insert this to mysql table like this

```
product_id = xyz , location_id=2, stock=5
product_id = xyz , location_id=5, stock=7
product_id = xyz , location_id=6, stock=8
```

What is the method?

```
def add_new(request): 
    product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
    location_id = request.POST.get('location_id')
    stock = request.POST.get('location_stock')
    p = Products_stock(product_id=product_id,location_id=location_id,stock=stock)
    p.save()
    response_data = {}
    response_data['status'] = 'true'
    response_data['message'] = 'success'
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), mimetype='application/javascript')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a solution from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4731596/1686265 . I changed my view like this. thanks @ Krish R.

```
def add_new(request): 
        product_id = Products.objects.get(code=code).id
        x = request.POST.getlist('location_id')
        y = request.POST.getlist('location_stock')
        zipped = zip(x, y)
        for x, y in zipped:
            z = Product_stocks(product_id=product_id,warehouse_id=x,stock=y)
            z.save()
        response_data = {}
        response_data['status'] = 'true'
        response_data['message'] = 'success'
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), mimetype='application/javascript')
```