# Django Template curly brackets inside curly brackets

Tags: python, django

```html
{% if hosts %}
    <div class="row">
        {% for host in hosts %}
            {% if host.type_of == "Backend" %}
                <div class="col-sm-3">{{ host.type_of }}</div>
               {{ headers.{{ forloop.counter0 }} }}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

I am sending arrays, hosts and headers from views to my template, I need to get element of header with the current index (getting the header[i])

Error says

```
Could not parse the remainder: '{{ forloop.counter0' from 'headers.{{ forloop.counter0'
```

Can't seem to find any examples regarding to this. How can I achieve what I want ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29794982/14131913

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there an equal number of hosts and headers? If so, you could use zip(), in your view, to zip them together as follows:

```
headers_and_hosts = zip(headers, hosts)
```

Then this would allow you to do something like this in your template:

```
{% for host, header in headers_and_hosts %}
   {% if host.type_of == "Backend" %}
      <div class="col-sm-3">{{ host.type_of }}</div>
      {{ header }}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841165/is-there-a-way-to-loop-over-two-lists-simultaneously-in-django

Comment: This was what I needed! Thank you