# Carousel with backend data showing all images or no images

Tags: javascript, html, django, bootstrap-5

I am running a Django application where I receive the list of images and in my template, I have the following code for Carousel.

The issue is if I use this class "carousel-inner active" while iterating all images are set active and all images are shown on a single screen, if not if I remove active and just keep carousel-inner no image is shown

```
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators/dots -->
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide-to="1"></button>
  </div>

  <!-- The slideshow/carousel -->
  <div class="carousel-inner active">
      {% for image in data.images %}
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="{{ image }}" alt="image 1" class="d-block" style="width:100%">
    </div>
      {% endfor %}

  <!-- Left and right controls/icons -->
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: You could use the for loop counter to control generation of the active class along the lines of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6963594/9473764)

Comment: i tried something like this it dint work .    <div class="carousel-inner active">
    {% for image in data.images %}
        <div class="carousel-item {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}active{% endif %}" id="slide{{ forloop.counter }}">
            <img src="{{ image }}" >
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>

Comment: Perhaps you could update your question with the new code and explain exactly in what it didn't work.

Comment: If you've solved your problem you should either post your solution as an answer if you think it might have value to other users (you can accept your own answer), or just delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to use a for-loop container inside div

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
{% for image in data.images %}
    <div class="carousel-item {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}active{% endif %}" id="slide{{ forloop.counter }}">
        <img src="{{ image }}" class="d-block" style="width:100%">
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```