# How to parse a array variable into a Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

So I have a views.py which contains the following code that is applicable to the problem.

```
def check(request):
    data = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        prompt = request.POST['pathway']
        youtube = request.POST.get('youtube')
        udemy = request.POST.get('udemy')
    # Uses the user's prompt to generate the roadmap
    data = scrapeSite(prompt)
    looprange = range(len(data))
    if youtube == "youtubego":
        ytid, yttitle,ytthumbnail = searchyt(prompt, data)
    context = {
        'ytid': ytid,
        'yttitle': yttitle,
        'loopnum': looprange,
        'ytthumbnail': ytthumbnail,
    }
    return render(request, 'generate.html', context)
```

basically it gets the thumbnails, titles and ids of a variable number of YouTube videos. They are all stored in different arrays. Each of these are assigned to a value in the context dictionary which is then sent to the template generate.html shown below

```
{% extends 'main.html'%}

{% block title %}CourseCounduit || A University In Your Pocket{% endblock title%}
{% block content %}
<h1>Your roadmap for</h1>
<div id="Course-container">
    {%for i in loopnum %}
    <div>
        <img src="{{ytthumbnail.i}}" alt="" sizes="100px"
            srcset="100px">
        <h5>{{yttitle.i}}</h5>
    </div>
    {%endfor%}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

so the main result i was expecting is for the div "course container " to be duplicated to the amount of loopnum specified in views.py and for each iteration the img tag would display the i<sup>th</sup> url of the array ytthumbnail and for the h5 tag to display the i <sup>th</sup> title in the yttitle array.

Currently the the divs are being created but the contents are not being displayed. I have confirmed that the arrays are being populated.

I want the divs to be duplicated to the loopnum and in each div the thumnail and the title to be shown.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to `zip(ytthumbnail, yttitle)` in your views and iterate with index.

Like,

In views:

```
def check(request):
    ...
    combined_data= zip(ytthumbnail, yttitle)
    context = {
        ...
        'combined_data': combined_data,
    }
    return render(request, 'generate.html', context)
```

In .html file,

```
{% for item in combined_data%}
<div>
    <img src="{{ item.0 }}" alt="" sizes="100px"
        srcset="100px">
    <h5>{{ item.1 }}</h5>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

To use, `{{ yttitle|index:forloop.counter0 }}` syntax, you need to register a custom *`index`* filter to facilitate the indexing of the array as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29794982/8353711)

Comment: It gave me the error "Could not parse the remainder: '[i]' from 'ytthumbnail[i]'"

Comment: Is `looprange == len(ytthumbnail) == len(yttitle)`?

Comment: yeah, i checked it and they both are the same

Comment: nope, still get the error Could not parse the remainder: '[loop.index0]' from 'ytthumbnail[loop.index0]'.

Comment: Have you copy pasted the code as it is? Miss use of `{{ }}` or `{% %}` could cause this issue.

Comment: Both solutions will produce syntax errors in the templates with the django template language. The second one could work if the correct syntax `{{ item.0 }}` and `{{ item.1 }}` is used.

Comment: Alright it works. Thanks for all of your time :)